# How to access Django's single set item?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I ran the following code in python shell:

> from main.models import ToDoList
> ls = ToDoList.objects.all()
> ls
> output: <QuerySet [<ToDoList: First List>, <ToDoList: Second List>]>

but when I use:

> ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=1)

it says:

> main.models.ToDoList.DoesNotExist: ToDoList matching query does not exist.

Comment: Its because you probably have deleted the object with id=1. Do ToDoList.objects.all().values() and check the id of both objects.

Comment: thank you for the help. It seems like I've somehow deleted the 1st item and now its shifted to 4th.Is there any way that I can change the id back to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `ToDoList.objects.first()` to get the first item.
or use `ToDoList.objects.get(pk=1)` to get item based on PK